# guidelines for developing a windows service which communicates with an Oracle server via ADO

Tags: delphi, windows-services, ado

I want to develop windows service in Delphi that communicates with an Oracle server via `ADO`.

Which  guidelines should I follow?

I already know `ADO`, but I don't have experience with the windows services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Tutorial for making a Service Application using Delphi](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/service/service.htm) is good point to start.
And If you want to connect database in an service app. you can create second thread in OnStart event of TService class.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint: I did have lot's of problems when developing a service using ADO to an Oracle server. After some testing the problem lied in the fact that the ADO driver from Oracle was unable to handle concurrent connections in multiple threads. In the end we used a single thread to do all ADO connections and sync the resulting datasets to the threads that did the processing.